# finished with non-zero exit value 2 when I use google login api

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-signin

I want to access the `google account` to *login my app*,and I get:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

My `build.grade`:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "nthu.nf.project.moocs"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 3
            versionName "1.2"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.5.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0'


    }
```

and in my `app/libs` I only use:

```
    YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar
    google-play-services.jar
    commons-io-2.4.jar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

play-services-identity:7.5.0, play-services-plus:7.5.0
and google-play-services.jar may cause the multiply libs conflict

Comment: what did you actually do to fix the issue though?